# assembly binding logging is turned off

Tags: asp.net, ajaxcontroltoolkit

I'm getting this error. Please help!

Parser Error
Description: An error occurred during the parsing of a resource required to service this request. Please review the following specific parse error details and modify your source file appropriately.

Parser Error Message: Could not load file or assembly 'AjaxControlToolkit' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.

Source Error:

```
Line 1:  <%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="index.aspx.cs" Inherits="index" %>
Line 2:  <%@ Register Assembly="AjaxControlToolkit" Namespace="AjaxControlToolkit" TagPrefix="asp" %>
Line 3:  
Line 4:  <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">


Source File: /skyscanner2/index.aspx    Line: 2
```

> Assembly Load Trace: The following
>   information can be helpful to
>   determine why the assembly
>   'AjaxControlToolkit' could not be
>   loaded.

```
WRN: Assembly binding logging is turned OFF.
To enable assembly bind failure logging, set the registry value [HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Fusion!EnableLog] (DWORD) to 1.
Note: There is some performance penalty associated with assembly bind failure logging.
To turn this feature off, remove the registry value [HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Fusion!EnableLog].
```

Comment: Do you have a reference to `AjaxControlToolkit.dll` in your project?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(Migrated from my comment above, so there's an answer.)

You need to have a reference to `AjaxControlToolkit.dll` in your project.